# Google Apps Script | Adding to a list only strings that has a size of 12

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a sheet with 1 column, there is in each cell a string with a size of 10 or 12.
My objective is : Make a list with only string of size 12.

I made a function that is very slow because it is a big loop :

```
function transfererCatVlans()             
{                                       
  let ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let VLANS = ss.getSheetByName('VLANS');
  let liste = [];
  for(let i = 1 ; i < VLANS.getLastRow() ; i++){
    if(VLANS.getRange(i,1).getFontSize()==12){
      liste.push([VLANS.getRange(i,1).getValue()]);
    }
  }
  console.log(liste);
  return liste;
}
```

Do you have a faster function to do the same thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the values and font sizes at once with [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [getFontSizes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontsizes), and loop through the retrieved arrays in order to minimize the number of requests to the spreadsheet:

```
function transfererCatVlans() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const VLANS = ss.getSheetByName('VLANS');
  const liste = [];
  const values = VLANS.getRange(1, 1, VLANS.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const fontSizes = VLANS.getRange(1, 1, VLANS.getLastRow()).getFontSizes();
  for (let i = 0; i < fontSizes.length; i++) {
    if (fontSizes[i][0] === 12) {
      liste.push(values[i]); // Use `values[i][0]` if you want to push the value and not an array containing it
    }
  }
  return liste;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i am on it I will give you a feedback soon

Comment: Thank you lambichus, I didn't thought about feeding two lists at the same time, thank you very much, it is so much faster! Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

Use [getFontSizes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontsizes) to get at once

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do i have to keep the loop ?

Comment: `getValues` returns a two-dimensional array of values. You have to loop across the rows.

Comment: Once all the values of my column in the list, i can't get their Size to filter my list. I think i didnt get your explanation.

Comment: `array.length` gives you the array size

Comment: I am talking about the Font size in the sheet. I would like to add to my list only the Values that have a size of 12 in my sheet

Comment: `values[i][0]` returns the string, `string.length` returns the string length (size)

Comment: From your point of view, the string "hello" has a lenght of 5. In this problem i am talking about the real Font Size of the Cell in google sheet, not the number of characters of the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235537/discussion-between-thibaud-garnier-and-idfurw).

Comment: Sorry, then use [getFontSizes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontsizes) instead